# Properly parse through JSON from an XML file with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, json

I'm reading an xml file with PHP and pulling it into jQuery via a .getJSON call, but I can't figure out how to iterate over it. I have the following XML:

```
<comments>
    <comment id='0'>
        <author>John Doe</author>
        <datetime>2011-06-05T11:13:00</datetime>
        <text>Message text</text>
    </comment>
    <comment id='1'>
        <author>John Doe</author>
        <datetime>2011-06-05T11:13:00</datetime>
        <text>Message text</text>
    </comment>
</comment>
```

I'm reading and sending it to the front end with PHP like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("comments.xml");
print json_encode($xml);
```

The JSON it produces is:

```
{ "comment" : [ 
      { "@attributes" : { "id" : "0" },
        "author" : "John Doe",
        "datetime" : "2011-06-05T11:13:00",
        "text" : "Message text"
      },
      { "@attributes" : { "id" : "1" },
        "author" : "John Doe",
        "datetime" : "2011-06-05T11:13:00",
        "text" : "Message text"
      }
] }
```

...and trying to figure out how to manipulate it in jQuery without much success. I've been reading tutorials and this site for hours, but no luck. How would I access the data? Here's the jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('xml.php',function(data) {
    html = '<div class="comments">';
    for (var i=0;i<data.comments;i++){
        var obj = data.comments.comment[i];
        html += '<div class="comment">\n';
        html += '   <span class="name">'+obj.author+'</span>\n';
        html += '</div>';
    }
    html += '</comments>';
    $('.comments').replaceWith(html);
});
```

The idea being to produce the following html:

```
<div class="comments">

    <div class="comment first">
        <span class="name">Jon Doe</span>
        <span class="text">Message Text</span>
        <div class="meta">6 minutes ago</div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
        <span class="name">John Doe</span>
        <span class="text">I hate blue. Can you get add more pink?</span>
        <div class="meta">2 hours ago</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**UPDATE**
Here's the final jQuery I put together based on the answers:

```
html = '<div class="comments">';
$.each(data.comment, function(key, comment) {
    html += '    <div class="comment">\n';
    html += '        <span class="name">'+comment.author+'</span>\n';
    html += '        <span class="text">'+comment.text+'</span>\n';
    html += '        <div class="meta">\n'+comment.datetime+'</div>\n';
    html += '    </div>';
});
html += '</div>';
$('.comments').replaceWith(html);
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you posted the generated JSON as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what errors you're getting:

```
$.getJSON('xml.php',function(data) {
    html = '<div class="comments">';
    $.each(data.comment, function(key, comment) {
        var comment_id = comment['@attributes'].id;
        html += '<div class="comment">\n';
        html += '   <span class="name">'+comment.author+'</span>\n';
        html += '</div>';

    });
    html += '</div>';
    $('.comments').replaceWith(html);
});
```

An [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3WXRz/).

Comment: Tried this, and got "undefined" in the proper place in the html.

Comment: If you don't post your JSON, we're not going to be able to help

Comment: Perfect! How would I access the attributes? The ID attribute, for example? I tried comment[0], comment['id'] with no luck. Also tried changing out the 'data.comment' line to just 'data' and then using comment.comment.author, etc for the other values to try to traverse up one level in the tree but that didn't work at all.

Comment: @Adam Nelson, thanks for that, updated the answer. Also updated it with a possible method for getting the id.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what tutorials you've read, but [take a look at this one](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2026-jQuery-Template-Markup-Langauge-JTML-vs-jQuery-Templates.htm) for the jQuery Template Markup Language (JTML).